# Locale does not work in Perl on FreeBSD

Tags: locale, freebsd, perl

The following does work (outputs a message in Russian about my attempt to open an nonexistent directory) for perl5 (revision 5 version 22 subversion 2) on Debian Linux (Bash):

`LANGUAGE=ru_RU.UTF-8 perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -Mlocale -e 'opendir my $fh, "afdsfd"; print $!, "\n"'`

But on FreeBSD perl5 (revision 5 version 20 subversion 3) it prints the message in English. Why does it not work on FreeBSD?

---

On FreeBSD:

```
$ locale -a | grep ru
ru_RU.CP1251
ru_RU.CP866
ru_RU.ISO8859-5
ru_RU.KOI8-R
ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Comment: Oh, I found that `LANGUAGE` is a GNU extension. But this does not solve my problem, because after replacing `LANGUAGE` with `LC_ALL`or `LANG` or `LC_MESSAGES` it does not work also :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Russian messages on FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE work with KOI8-R, but do not work with UTF-8.

Example:

```
perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -MPOSIX -e 'setlocale(POSIX::LC_ALL, "ru_RU.KOI8-R"); opendir my $fh, "afdsfd"; print $!, "\n"' | iconv -f KOI8-R -t UTF-8
```